# Change viewing quarters in visual Business Intelligence Projects

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ssis, olap-cube

I have Business Intelligence Projects project in VS. I create cube, and when I'm browsing data and generate raports I have quarters in format 1,2,3,4. I want to show quarters in format Q1, Q2, ...

When I'm changing quarter format I still get quaters in format 1,2 ...

example:

[image]

How to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.

To do this is needed *calculated column* in table where we need this with expresion:

```
case
 when CalendarQuarter = ‘1’ then ‘Q1’
 when CalendarQuarter = ‘2’ then ‘Q2’
 when CalendarQuarter = ‘3’ then ‘Q3’
 else ‘Q4’
end
```